# How to send a message inside an event telethon, telegram?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, telegram, telethon

I wrote a function that starts when a message is written to the telegram channel. If the message is `"start"` then the function prints 1, while if `"stop"` message is received then condition is set and it leads to stop while loop in threading. Then it should send message through telethon but I am getting an error:

```
from threading import Event, Thread
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
import telebot
condition = Event()

api_id = ******

api_hash = '*******'

client = TelegramClient('my_session', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

# telegram bot
token_1_bot = '5******'
chat_id = -********



bot_1 = telebot.TeleBot(token_1_bot)


def do_smth():
    while not condition.is_set():
        print(1)

    client.send_message('@bots_username', 'Hi bot you are bot')
    print(2)

@bot_1.message_handler(content_types='text')
def on_message(message):
    if "start" in message.text:

        # open documents page
        # Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(application_fill(id, channel),)).start()
        Thread(target=do_smth, args=()).start()

    elif message.text == 'stop':
        condition.set()


bot_1.infinity_polling()
```

the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "F:/aktaustroyexpert/tel_test.py", line 50, in do_smth
    client.send_message('@bot_username', 'Hi bot you are bot')
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telethon\sync.py", line 35, in syncified
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.

C:\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py:951: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MessageMethods.send_message' was never awaited
  del exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb
```

What is wrong? How can I send a message to a bot (through telethon) from a simple function(this function is called when the "start" message is received)?

So my main task is to send `stop` message to bots from the computer which opens the URL, in a way that other bots stop opening the URL.

Answer (score 0):

`await client.send_message('@bot_username', 'Hi bot you are bot')`

Comment: in that case,  should I put async in from of the def do_smth()?